# Byte32 to uint and then back to byte32

Tags: solidity, web3js, uint256, abiencoderv2

I have to bitpack two uint128 values into a uint256, then get back the two original uint128s.

To encode the values I'm using:

```
function encode256(uint128 a, uint128 b) pure public returns (uint256) {
    return uint256(bytes32(abi.encodePacked(a, b)));
}
```

For: `a=1, b=16` we get
`a=0x00000000000000000000000000000001`
`b=0x00000000000000000000000000000010` which leads to `0x0000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000010` which cast to uint256 is `340282366920938463463374607431768211472`.

The issue is decoding it back to the originals. To unravel the encoded `uint256` back to the two `uint128` I wrote the following code:

```
let hex = numberToHex("340282366920938463463374607431768211472") //1 /16
hex = padRight(hex, 64)
hex = hex.replace('0x','') 
const half = Math.ceil(hex.length / 2);    
const firstHalf = hex.slice(0, half)
const secondHalf = hex.slice(half)
console.log(firstHalf)
console.log(secondHalf)
```

But the two numbers coming out are
`a=10000000000000000000000000000001`,
`b=00000000000000000000000000000000`.

I'm not sure how the encoding is happening and wondering where I am going wrong in the encoding or decoding process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are padding right. You need to actually pad left:

```js
hex = padLeft(hex, 64)
```

If you [convert](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-hex.html) `340282366920938463463374607431768211472` to hex, it would be: `100000000000000000000000000000010`. If we left pad it, it will be: `0000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000010`.

When slicing the first part, it will be: `00000000000000000000000000000001`.
When slicing the second part, it will be: `00000000000000000000000000000010`.

Which is what you want.